# Как правильно организовать отношение между квадратом и прямоугольником с точки зрения наследования?

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Представим, что у нас есть два класса: прямоугольник `Rectangle` и квадрат `Square`. Как между ними правильно организовать отношение с точки зрения наследования?

С одной стороны, квадрат - это частный случай прямоугольника, поэтому квадрат будет наследником, а прямоугольник - родителем (и это логично, ведь если изображать в кругах Эйлера, то круг Квадрат будет внутри круга Прямоугольник).

С другой стороны, с точки зрения ООП все должно быть наоборот, т.е. прямоугольник должен наследоваться от квадрата, поскольку квадрату достаточно знать длину одной стороны, в то время как прямоугольнику - две.

Чтобы не быть голословным, приведу 2 примера на языке C#.

1. Rectangle наследует Square:

   ```
   public class Square
   {
       public int SideA { get; set; }

       public Square(int sideA)
       {
           SideA = sideA;
       }

       public virtual int Perimeter => 4 * SideA;
   }

   public class Rectangle : Square
   {
       public int SideB { get; set; }

       public Rectangle(int sideA, int sideB) : base(sideA)
       {
           SideB = sideB;
       }

       public override int Perimeter => 2 * (SideA + SideB);
   }
   ```

   Здесь функциональность расширяется благодаря появлению новой стороны `SideB`, однако пришлось переопределить свойство Perimeter. С точки зрения ООП, на мой взгляд, все хорошо (поправьте, если я не прав).
2. Square наследует Rectangle:

   ```
   public class Square : Rectangle
   {
       public Square(int sideA) : base(sideA, sideA)
       {
       }
   }

   public class Rectangle
   {
       public int SideA { get; set; }
       public int SideB { get; set; }        

       public Rectangle(int sideA, int sideB)
       {
           SideA = sideA;
           SideB = sideB;
       }

       public int Perimeter => 2 * (SideA + SideB);
   }
   ```

   Здесь, если рассматривать класс Square, для него появилось
   "бесполезное" свойство SideB, которое является копией SideA. Т.е. по
   факту, с точки зрения ООП, функциональность сузилась.

Лично мне больше нравится второй вариант, он более лаконичный и правильный с точки зрения логики, но все же, как же правильно поступать в таком случае?

Comment: Наследование (обобщение) - это операция пересечения по множеству атрибутов и функций объектов. Правильный способ - это наследование прямоугольника и квадрата, от абстрактного общего предка. Будет время - выступлю более подробно

Comment: Много вариантов, решение зависит от конкретной ситуации (что должны делать квадрат и прямоугольник). Обзор можете посмотреть здесь: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Comment: @defaultlocale ух ты, я даже не знал, что по этому поводу есть целая статья на википедии. Спасибо за ссылку

Comment: Имхо, в данном случае наследование избыточно. Квадрат можно рассмотреть, как прямоугольник с определенными значениями свойств (`a == b`), а проверку эту добавить методом `bool IsSquare()` в прямоугольник. Для примера: никогда не видел в графических библиотеках метода `DrawSquare(int side)`, обычно там `DrawRectangle(int width, int height)`. Если же все таки нужно наследовать, то правильнее *Square **is-a** rectangle*, но никак не наоборот.

Comment: Рекомендую приятный на вид и восприятие сайт https://refactoring.guru/ru

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имхо, нужно создать абстрактный класс `Shape` и от него пронаследовать `Square` и `Rectangle`.

А причина проста: полиморфизм.

Допустим, мы пронаследовали `Rectangle` от `Square` и создали метод `public CalcSome(Square square)`.

Мы абсолютно легитимно можем в него передать `Rectangle` так как он является наследником.

Так вот, когда пользователь будет пользоваться этим чудо-методом, то он будет полагать, что работает с квадратом и ожидать поведения квадрата, а по факту туда может попасть Rectangle.

И как следствии логично иметь абстрактный класс `Shape`, который не дает пользователю ложные предположения.

Кстати, вот [тут](https://blog.byndyu.ru/2009/10/blog-post_29.html) прямо в первом примере описывается почти ваша ситуация и говорится, что это противоречит Принцип замещения Лисков

Comment: Несомненно можно, но тогда потеряется информация о том, что квадрат - разновидность прямоугольника. Т.е. в любой методы работы с прямоугольником уже не передать квадрат.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, да, но все равно как-то не естественно это выглядит. С таким же успехом можно вообще все запихать в 1 класс и если A=B, то это квадрат.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно - "Square наследует Rectangle". Но не так, как у вас. У вас почему-то переопределен только конструктор, но не переопределены и не скрыты свойства SideA и SideB, поэтому квадрат, хоть и создается сначала с равными сторонами, впоследствии может обзавестись разными. Должно быть как-то так:

```
public class Square : Rectangle
{
    int _side;

    public Square(int side) : base(side, side)
    {

    }        

    public override int SideA { get => _side; set => _side = value; }
    public override int SideB { get => _side; set => _side = value; }

}

public class Rectangle
{
    int _SideA;
    int _SideB;

    public virtual int SideA { get { return _SideA; } set { this._SideA = value; } }
    public virtual int SideB { get { return _SideB; } set { this._SideB = value; } }

    public Rectangle(int sideA, int sideB)
    {
        SideA = sideA;
        SideB = sideB;
    }

    public int Perimeter => 2 * (SideA + SideB);
}
```

На самом деле, о "лишнем свойстве SideB" тут говорить несколько неправильно. Квадрат - все еще прямоугольник, у него есть обе стороны, просто они равны. Понятие "Квадрат" расширяет понятие "Прямоугольник" в данном случае дополнительным ограничением на равенство его свойств SideA и SideB. Если вас смущает, что в коде вида `square.SideA = 1; square.SideB = 2` одно из значений будет "молча съедено", можно заменить один из сеттеров на `throw new InvalidOperationException("Только одна сторона квадрата является изменяемой");`.

Comment: А, ну да, про свойства я не позаботился, забыл.

Comment: Просто идея в том, что квадрату не нужно свойство SideB, оно попросту лишнее для квадрата, в этом была суть вопроса

Comment: @AndreiKhotko обновил

Comment: сеттеры вообще не нужны

Answer (score 2):

Раньше такие темы помечались как "порождающие бесконечные прения" и закрывались безжалостно. :-)

А по существу, в случае программистских классификаций надо вводить новый базовый класс - отрезок (или измерение). Тогда класс квадрат содержит один отрезок, а класс прямоугольник содержит два отрезка. Тогда сохраняются привычные круги Эйлера - прямоугольник это квадрат плюс еще один отрезок (еще одно измерение). Хотя кто сказал, что наследование в программировании должно повторять отношения вложенности множеств в математике? Если удобнее сделать как-то по-другому, то нужно делать по-другому.

Comment: У автора конкретный код на C# с вполне конкретными багами. Если кто закрывал такое как "порождающие бесконечные прения", на мыло таких закрывателей.

Answer (score 1):

стоит упомянуть о принципе подстановки Лисков.

если взять первый пример:
- прямоугольник наследуется от квадрата
- допустим, у квадрата есть геометрические методы со специфичной реализацией для квадрата
тогда придется переопределять их для прямоугольника

во втором примере мы обходим это стороной, хоть поля и дублируются

теперь мое мнение. в данном случае подойдет второй вариант, или оставить только "прямоугольник", не создавать "квадрат". но для каждого как будто похожего случая решение может быть разное

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая книга: "Введение в системы баз данных", К. Дж. Дейт, восьмое издание, 2005 год.

В главе 20 "Наследование типов" автор высказывает свои мысли по поводу наследование Circle-Ellipse. Мысли весьма интересные и сильно отличающиеся от общепринятых.

Дело в том, что автор большой специалист по реляционным базам данным и его идеи основаны именно на этом. Он с жаром отстаивает *правильность* модели данных, основанную на *отношениях*. В его мире всё должно соответствовать строгости реляционной алгебры и реляционных исчислений.

Суть в том, что объект должен менять свой тип, в зависимости от выполнения ограничений, наложенных на тип. Если изначально был создан эллипс с отношением сторон, например, 5 и 6, то при изменении второго на 5, обе оси становятся одинаковы и объект должен поменять свой тип - стать окружностью. И наоборот. Насколько это осуществимо в мейнстримовых языках программирования - м-м-м, явно малоприменимо. Но мысль интересная.

В комментариях дали ссылку [Circle-ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) (продублировал её, чтобы все увидели, т. к. комментарии не все читают). Из статьи я узнал, что мысли Дейта отнюдь не оригинальны, как я полагал, и другие авторы тоже выдвигают похожие идеи. Прочтение данной вики-статьи вполне заменит наполненную зубодробительными выкладками главу книги.

Comment: Буду ждать, спасибо